# Extjs how to parametrize the store proxy url

Tags: extjs

I'm new to extjs and I'm trying to parametrize the store proxy url.

In my view I'm building the store like this:

```
store: Ext.create('mystore', {
                partofurl: 'url'
            })
```

And my store:

```
Ext.define('mystore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.mystore',
    model: 'mymodel',
    restful: true,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        headers: {
           'Accept': '*/*',
           'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': localStorage.token
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            rootProperty: 'data'
        },
        actionMethods: {
           read: 'GET'
        },
        api: {
           read: 'http://url' + this.partofurl,
           create: 'http://url' + this.partofurl,
           update: 'http://url' + this.partofurl,
           destroy: 'http://url' + this.partofurl,
        },
        autoSave: true
    }
});
```

I tried this also:

```
store: Ext.create('mystore', {
                    proxy.api.read = 'http://url' + partofurl
                })
```

and so... but it keeps telling me:

> Uncaught Error: You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extjs store proxy api throws error does not recognize url when passing it as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976344/extjs-store-proxy-api-throws-error-does-not-recognize-url-when-passing-it-as-a-v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [the example on fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s3l).

> You can't use `this` in Ext.define. 
>   You need to set url in constructor
>   or override the buildUrl method.

Answer (score 0):

On your second attempt you just did not create the store config object properly.

Try this:

```
var store = Ext.create('mystore', {
    proxy: {
        api: {
            read: 'http://url' + partofurl
        }
    }
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s5l) (line 22).